# Standard error of a sampling distribution

Tags: statistics

In 2008 the Better Business Bureau settled 75% of complaints they received (USA Today, March 2, 2009). Suppose you have been hired by the Better Business Bureau to investigate the complaints they received this year involving new car dealers. You plan to select a sample of new car dealer complaints to estimate the proportion of complaints the Better Business Bureau is able to settle. Assume the population proportion of complaints settled for new car dealers is .75, the same as the overall proportion of complaints settled in 2008.

a. Suppose you select a sample of 450 complaints involving new car dealers. Show the sampling distribution of p.

How do I find the standard error of σ(p) =

b. Based upon a sample of 450 complaints, what is the probability that the sample proportion will be within .04 of the population proportion (to 4 decimals)?

Comment: To prevent down-votes or votes to close your Question, I hope you will edit your question with some progress towards a solution. Maybe my 'Answer' has enough clues to help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are outlines that may help:

For (a), I think you must mean the sampling distribution of $\hat p = X/n,$
where $X$ is the number of settled complaints among $n$ dealers. Assuming the dealers are selected at random, $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n, p),$ which has
$E(X) = np$ and $Var(X) = np(1-p).$ Then theorems about expectations and
variances of linear functions of a random variable give $$E(\hat p) = E(X/n) 
= \frac 1nE(X) = \frac{1}{n} (np) = p.$$
Somewhat similarly, $Var(\hat p) = \frac{p(1-p)}{n}$ and the standard error of $\hat p$ is
$SD(\hat p) = \sqrt{\frac{p(1-p)}{n}}.$

For (b), you want 
$$P(|\hat p - p|\le .04) = P(-.04 \le \hat p - p \le   .04) =
P\left(\frac{-.04}{SD(\hat p)} \le \frac{\hat p - p}{SD(\hat p)} \le \frac{.04}{SD(\hat p)} \right),$$
where $Z = \frac{\hat p - p}{SD(\hat p)}$ is approximately standard normal.
You are told to use $p = .75$ and $n = 450.$ So you can evaluate $SD(\hat p)$ and find the required probability, perhaps using printed normal tables or using software.